# When multiplying a number with an exponent attached do you add or multiply the exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, exponentiation

Example: Does $1p^2(1p^3)$ equal $1p^6$ or $1p^5$?

Comment: What is up with the $1$s in your formula?

Comment: Sometimes students are taught that $\alpha x^a \cdot \beta x^b = \alpha \beta x^{a+b}$, and are reminded that even if $\alpha=1$ it is still present so they can use the formula and not be confused.  It should be mentioned however as ThomasAndrews points out, that it is redundant, and we almost never write down a multiplication by $1$ since $1\cdot k = k$ for any number $k$, we prefer to write it without multiplication by $1$ since it saves space and sanity.

Comment: see http://mathontrack.comze.com/exponentials2.html for a good explaination.

Answer (score 7):

$p^2=p\cdot p$ and $p^3=p\cdot p\cdot p$ so $$p^2\cdot p^3=(p\cdot p)\cdot(p\cdot p\cdot p) = p\cdot p\cdot p\cdot p\cdot p = p^5$$

Basically, this is the associative law.

Answer (score 1):

It equals $p^5$ because in this case you add the exponents. However if you were given something along the lines of $(p^2)^3$, then you multiply them and get $p^6$.

Edit: If you are still having trouble, try plugging in values for $p$ and find out what happens.